# Using scanf in for loop only prompts on first iteration

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm creating a program where for each iteration of a `for` loop, I'm prompted to enter input. However I'm only prompted on the first iteration of the loop, and not for any subsequent iterations.

Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void get_letters(char *letters, int number);

int main() {
    char letters[10];
    int number;
    memset(letters, '\0', 10);
    scanf("%d", &number);
    get_letters(letters, number);
    printf("%s\n", letters);
    return 0;
}

void get_letters(char *letters, int number)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        printf("bruh\n");
        scanf(" %c", letters[i]);
    }
}
```

This is my output when I run the program:
As seen, the program exits after the first iteration without calling subsequent prompts.
[image]

Comment: `scanf(" %c", &letters[0]);` You need to pass a pointer to `scanf`. If you're not getting a warning about the incorrect argument type you should turn your warning level up. You're also reading into the same letter each time.

Comment: You are not using gcc correctly, the right command is `gcc -Wall -Werror q1.c`.

Comment: @SamuelLiew: can you please explain why you deleted Geekyvinayak's answer?

Comment: Use `scanf(" %c", letters+i);` instead of `scanf(" %c", letters[i]);`. `scanf` parameter must be the address of the nth character of `letters`, and not `letters` nth character.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the ith letter to scanf while you should pass its adress

```
void get_letters(char *letters, int number){
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        printf("bruh\n");
        scanf(" %c", &letters[i]);
    }
}
```